# R é uma linguagem orientada a objetos?

Tags: r, terminologia

Uma dúvida teórica de quem usa (e de quem não usa) o `r` é a de saber se esta linguagem de programação é (ou não) orientada a objetos. Já vi comentários no SOen que diziam o seguinte:

*`r` não é orientado a objetos, e sim uma linguagem funcional, mas com traços da linguagem OO*.

Desta maneira:

- `r` é uma linguagem orientada a objetos, funcional ou um agregado das duas? Por quê?
- o que significa dizer que `r` é vetorizado? E, por que esta característica presente no `r` é tão importante frente a outras linguagens de programação?

Comment: Você pode descrever o que está sentindo falta na resposta?

Comment: A sua resposta está excelente, @Tomás. No entanto, gostaria que mais pessoas pudessem contribuir com outros conhecimentos (teóricos, não opinativos) de outras linguagens de programação para esta resposta. Algo como citar a semelhança e diferença entre encapsulamento em Java e em R, e também o mesmo para o polimorfismo entre estas duas linguagens. Sei que isto não faz parte do escopo da pergunta, mas, se for o caso, posso editá-la ou sinta-se à vontade para isso. Pensei em criar uma nova pergunta para esta finalidade, mas decidi oferecer a recompensa ao invés disso. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Estou perguntando para poder complementar ela mesmo. Gosto da idéia de mais pessoas ajudarem a debater essa questão com o empenho que merece. Só quero poder ser uma delas :P

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A frase citada acima do SOen está correta. De acordo com o John Chambers, criador do [r](/questions/tagged/r),

> Tudo o que existe no R é um objeto.
>
> Tudo o que acontece no R é o chamado de uma função.

Isso cria a curiosa situação de que uma função é, ela mesma, um objeto.

Veja a diferença entre o [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame) no [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) ([python](/questions/tagged/python), orientado a objeto):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
                    'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                    'C' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"])})
df
     A          B      C  
0  1.0 2013-01-02   test  
1  1.0 2013-01-02  train 
2  1.0 2013-01-02   test  
3  1.0 2013-01-02  train
```

e no [r](/questions/tagged/r) (pacote [base](/questions/tagged/base), mais funcional):

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1,
                 B = as.Date("2013-01-02"),
                 C = c("test","train","test","train"))
df
  A          B     C
1 1 2013-01-02  test
2 1 2013-01-02 train
3 1 2013-01-02  test
4 1 2013-01-02 train
```

Agora que temos nosso `df` no `pandas` e no `r-base`, podemos ver a diferença entre as abordagens funcional e orientada a objeto para, por exemplo, verificar o tipo de informação contida em cada coluna.

Na orientação a objeto, o próprio objeto tem contido em si uma propriedade (as vezes é um método) que nos permite fazer isso.

```
df.dtypes

A           float64
B    datetime64[ns]
C          category
dtype: object
```

Já na orientação mais funcional, esta informação não é acessada pelo próprio objeto, mas por uma função. Ou seja, o "método" não "vive" dentro do objeto, mas fora e independente dele.

```
class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Ocorre que a função `class()` só nos traz a última informação que o `pandas` trouxe (a última linha). No `R`, para ver a classe das colunas, devemos aplicar a função separadamente para cada coluna. Isso é feito via `Map` (ou mais comummente, `sapply()`), que é uma funcionalidade comum de encontrar em linguagens funcionais. Assim temos

```
sapply(df, class) # ou Map(class, df)
        A         B         C 
"numeric"    "Date"  "factor"
```

A vetorização no `R` apenas diz respeito ao fato de o `R` ser capaz de relacionar dois vetores de tamanhos diferentes. Desta maneira, não é necessário escrever um loop, por exemplo, para somar um vetor de 5 números com um vetor de 1 ou dois números.

```
1:5 + 1
[1] 2 3 4 5 6
1:5 + 1:2
[1] 2 4 4 6 6
Warning message:
In 1:5 + 1:2 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Como se pode ver no aviso do segundo exemplo acima, esta vetorização pode ter alguns percalços. Para não estender ainda mais esta resposta, recomendo ler [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282059/43953)